# what is the function of NSObject in StoryBoard / Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, tdd, nsobject

I am currently following a video tutorial course about test driven development of iOS in Swift, but when testing Table View in View Controller, I get stuck, since I don't understand why we need NSObject in Interface builder like the picture below:

Movie Library Data Service is inheritted NSObject class:

[image]

the class of `MovieLibraryDataService` is like this:

```
import UIKit

class MovieLibraryDataService: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }


}
```

and the `MovieLibraryDataService` class will be used in XCTestCase is like this :

```
@testable import FilmFest
class LibraryViewControllerTests: XCTestCase {

    var sut: LibraryViewController!

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
        sut = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LibraryViewControllerID") as! LibraryViewController
        _ = sut.view
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    // MARK: Nil Checks
    func testLibraryVC_TableViewShouldNotBeNil() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.libraryTableView)
    }

    // MARK: Data Source
    func testDataSource_ViewDidLoad_SetsTableViewDataSource() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.libraryTableView.dataSource)
        XCTAssertTrue(sut.libraryTableView.dataSource is MovieLibraryDataService)
    }

    // MARK: Delegate
    func testDelegate_ViewDidLoad_SetsTableViewDelegate() {
        XCTAssertNotNil(sut.libraryTableView.delegate)
        XCTAssertTrue(sut.libraryTableView.delegate is MovieLibraryDataService)
    }

    // MARK: Data Service Assumptions
    func testDataService_ViewDidLoad_SingleDataServiceObject() {
        XCTAssertEqual(sut.libraryTableView.dataSource as! MovieLibraryDataService, sut.libraryTableView.delegate as! MovieLibraryDataService)
    }



}
```

and the definition of LibraryViewController:

```
import UIKit

class LibraryViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var libraryTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet var dataService: MovieLibraryDataService!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.libraryTableView.dataSource = dataService
        self.libraryTableView.delegate = dataService
    }


}
```

I really don't understand why I need to make that `MovieLibraryDataService` class

I usually use:

```
self.libraryTableView.dataSource = self
self.libraryTableView.delegate = self
```

but why do I need to write :

```
self.libraryTableView.dataSource = dataService
self.libraryTableView.delegate = dataService
```

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

You can use `NSObject` on the `Storyboard` for different purposes, one of them could be also the delegation. Instead of setting it programatically like:

```
self.libraryTableView.dataSource = self
self.libraryTableView.delegate = self
```

you can hold <kbd>control</kbd> and then set the corresponding delegates like below:

[image]

### Original Answer

Because `MovieLibraryDataService` that conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` and not your `LibraryViewController`.

If you want to change it as you are always used to, change your code to:

```
class LibraryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var libraryTableView: UITableView!
    var dataService = MovieLibraryDataService()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.libraryTableView.dataSource = self
        self.libraryTableView.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Personally I would suggest to keep it as you have it, as **View Controllers** tend to grow and become like we call it [Massive View Controller](https://academy.realm.io/posts/andy-matuschak-refactor-mega-controller/)

Answer (score 0):

`MovieLibraryDataService` is just another class which implements `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`, with the difference that the storyboard instantiates it and that `storyboard-created` instance is bound via the `IBOutlet` `@IBOutlet var dataService: MovieLibraryDataService!`. All objects in the storyboard are `storyboard-created`, that’s why one has to bind them to variables to use if they are not bound to other variables you use already.

Naming the variable `dataService` is just a fancy way of saying that it is supposed to `serve`, in this case as `dataSource and delegate` for a tableView, since it implements those delegate-protocols.

Since the `dataService` is instantiated by the storyboard, you could try if you can bind the `dataService` inside the storyboard to `tableView`. This is possible because you have the `dataService` referencable in the storyboard. This would replace setting `dataSource and delegate` in the `viewController`.

#### Another example

`AppDelegate` is also an `NSObject` inside the Storyboard so the `UIApplication/NSApplication` inside the storyboard is able to reference that to use, avoids having to set up `AppDelegate` yourself outside a storyboard. (Would otherwise be ugly, maybe that’s macOS only though, since mac apps have to show a `Menu` even if its empty.)

Comment: This is a `Cocoa Touch` app not `Cocoa`, therefore `NSTableViewDelegate` is out of scope here. As a beginner this would confuse me more rather than help me.